# get state in a function object casted to a std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, function-object, std-function

I want to retrieve state from a function object. But the function object has been casted to a `function<>` template. How can I do it?

I mean:

function object:

```
class Counter {
private:
    int counter_;
public:
    Counter():counter_(0) {cout << "Constructor() called" << endl;}
    Counter(int a):counter_(a) {cout << "Constructor(a) called" << endl;}

    void operator()(int sum) {
        cout << counter_++ + sum << endl;
    }

int getCounter() { return counter_;}
};
```

In main. My first step is use object directly:

```
int main() {
    Counter a(10);
    a(0);
    a(0);

    cout << "Counter: " << a.getCounter() << endl;
```

Its shows:

> Constructor(a) called
>
> 10
>
> 11
>
> Counter: 12

It's ok and it's what I expected.

But in

```
Counter b(10);
function<void(int)> f = b;
f(0);
f(0);
cout << "Counter: " << b.getCounter() << endl;
```

It shows

> Constructor(a) called
>
> 10
>
> 11
>
> Counter: 10

Argh!, I supposed that f was a wrapper of real object so modifying `f` we really modify `b`.  No: `f` has a copy of `b`, but I can't call to `f.getCounter()` so How can I get State (counter_ var) from `f`?

I can't use directly `Counter` class (in this example) because I have some other similar classes with same signature "void(int)" And I want to use them in indistinctly in a caller function.

I can avoid `std::function` template at all using a common base class for all my function object but I think there is a solution more C++11 with STL and templates...

So, Is there that solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a cast:

```
function<void(int)> f = b;
```

A `std::function` is been constructed, with a copy of your function object as its target.

You can either make the target a reference to your function object:

```
function<void(int)> f = std::ref(b);
```

Or let `f` contain a copy but then retrieve that copy from `f`:

```
Counter* c = f.target<Counter>();
cout << "Counter: " << c->getCounter() << endl;
```

It's usually safer to let `f` contain a copy as you don't ned to worry about the lifetime of `b`.

Answer (score 3):

Create the function from a reference wrapper:

```
function<void(int)> f = std::ref(b);
```

giving the result:

```
Constructor(a) called
10
11
Counter: 12
```

Of course, you need to make sure that the function isn't invoked after the counter is destroyed.

If you need to access the counter from the function object, then use its `target` member:

```
if (Counter * c = f.target<Counter>()) {
    std::cout << "Counter: " << c->getCounter() << '\n';
} else {
    std::cout << "Not a counter.\n";
}
```

Comment: You can use `f.target<Counter>()` to access it.

Comment: Works great! And you can still use original object "b" to get the same result.